# Problema com titulos no site,

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Aqui está o [site](http://apcefsp-homolog.adttemp.com.br) para vocês dar uma olhada.

O problema é o seguinte, na notícia principal e nas sub notícias existe esses `title` que está com um espaço meio gigante entre uma linha e outra

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
... agora nas colunas abaixo os titulos estão mais "proximos" como consigo arrumar isso ?

Aqui está o código do index do site.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9 border-right">
            <div class="main-content" id="main">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">

                        <!-- Destaques -->
                        <section id="destaques" class="destaques">
                            <h4 class="section-title">
                                <!-- Remover CSS Inline-->

                            </h4>
                            <?php

                            $posts = get_posts(array(
                                'numberposts'   => 1,
                                'post_type'     => 'post',
                                'meta_key'      => '_ag_featured_post',
                                'meta_value'    => 'principal',
                                'orderby'       => 'date',
                                'order'         => 'DESC'
                            ));

                            foreach ($posts as $post):

                                setup_postdata($post); ?>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                    <article>
                                        <figure>
                                            <div class="destaques-body">
                                                <div class="title"><p style="color:#ff6600; font-size:270%;"><b><?php the_title(); ?></b></p></div>
                                                <div class="title">
                                                <h4><?php the_excerpt(); ?></h4>
                                                </div>                                           
                                            </div>

                                        </figure>
                                    </article>
                                </a>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </section>



                        <!-- Destaques Small -->
                        <section id="destaques-items">
                            <div class="destaques-small">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <?php

                                    $posts = get_posts(array(
                                        'numberposts'   => 4,
                                        'post_type'     => 'post',
                                        'meta_key'      => '_ag_featured_post',
                                        'meta_value'    => 'secundaria',
                                        'orderby'       => 'date',
                                        'order'         => 'DESC'
                                    ));

                                    foreach ($posts as $post):

                                        setup_postdata($post); ?>
                                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">
                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                                <article>
                                                    <div class="title">
                                                        <figure>
                                                            <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                                                        </figure>
                                                        <figcaption>
                                                            <p style="font-size:130%;"><b><?php the_title(); ?></b></p>
                                                        </figcaption>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="content">
                                                        <p><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_excerpt(),20); ?></p>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="link">Leia mais</a>
                                                </article>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </section>

                    </div>


                </div>

                <b> <p style="border-widget:1px; background-color:#D6D6D6; text-align:right;"> <a style="color:#FF8000;" href="http://www.apcefsp.org.br/category/noticias">>Mais Notícias</a></p></b>  



                <!-- News Section -->
                <div class="news-wrap" id="news-section">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <section class="news">
                                <h4 class="section-title">
                                    <a href="<?= get_site_url(null, 'category/aposentados') ?>" target="_self">Aposentados</a>
                                </h4>
                                <?php

                                $posts = get_posts(array(
                                    'numberposts'   => 3,
                                    'post_type'     => 'post',
                                    'category_name' => 'aposentados',
                                    'orderby'       => 'date',
                                    'order'         => 'DESC'
                                ));

                                $count = 0;

                                foreach ($posts as $post):

                                    setup_postdata($post);

                                    if($count == 0): ?>
                                        <article class="news-destaque">
                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                                <figure>
                                                    <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, 'ag-apcef-large'); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                                                </figure>
                                                <div class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
                                            </a>
                                                <div class="content">
                                                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                                </div>

                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="link">Leia mais</a>

                                        </article>
                                    <?php else: ?>
                                        <article class="news-reduced">
                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                                        </article>
                                    <?php endif;

                                    $count++;

                                endforeach; ?>
                            </section>

                            <a href="<?= get_site_url(null, 'category/aposentados') ?>" class="btn-list-all" target="_self">Veja todos</a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <section class="news">
                                <h4 class="section-title">
                                    <a href="<?= get_site_url(null, 'category/unidades-de-lazer') ?>" target="_self">Unidades de Lazer</a>
                                </h4>
                                <?php

                                $posts = get_posts(array(
                                    'numberposts'   => 3,
                                    'post_type'     => 'post',
                                    'category_name' => 'unidades-de-lazer',
                                    'orderby'       => 'date',
                                    'order'         => 'DESC'
                                ));

                                $count = 0;

                                foreach ($posts as $post):

                                    setup_postdata($post);

                                    if($count == 0): ?>
                                        <article class="news-destaque">
                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                                <figure>
                                                    <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, 'ag-apcef-large'); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                                                </figure>
                                                <div class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
                                            </a>
                                            <div class="content">
                                                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                            </div>

                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="link">Leia mais</a>

                                        </article>
                                    <?php else: ?>
                                        <article class="news-reduced">
                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                                        </article>
                                    <?php endif;

                                    $count++;

                                endforeach; ?>
                            </section>

                            <a href="<?= get_site_url(null, 'category/unidades-de-lazer') ?>" class="btn-list-all" target="_self">Veja todos</a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <section class="news">
                                <h4 class="section-title">
                                    <a href="<?= get_site_url(null, 'eventos-e-lazer') ?>" target="_self">Eventos</a>
                                </h4>
                                <?php

                                $posts = get_posts(array(
                                    'numberposts'   => 3,
                                    'post_type'     => 'post',
                                    'category_name' => 'eventos-e-lazer',
                                    'orderby'       => 'date',
                                    'order'         => 'DESC'
                                ));

                                $count = 0;

                                foreach ($posts as $post):

                                    setup_postdata($post);

                                    if($count == 0): ?>
                                        <article class="news-destaque">
                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                                <figure>
                                                    <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, 'ag-apcef-large'); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                                                </figure>
                                                <div class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
                                            </a>
                                            <div class="content">
                                                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                            </div>

                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="link">Leia mais</a>

                                        </article>
                                    <?php else: ?>
                                        <article class="news-reduced">
                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                                        </article>
                                    <?php endif;

                                    $count++;

                                endforeach; ?>
                            </section>

                            <a href="<?= get_site_url(null, 'category/eventos-e-lazer') ?>" class="btn-list-all" target="_self">Veja todos</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>



                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
            <p style="border-widget:1px; background-color:#D6D6D6;"> </p>
            <!-- Iniciando segunda coluna -->

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                            <section class="news">
                                <h4 class="section-title">
                                    <a href="<?= get_site_url(null, 'category/esportes') ?>" target="_self">Esportes</a>
                                </h4>
                                <?php

                                $posts = get_posts(array(
                                    'numberposts'   => 3,
                                    'post_type'     => 'post',
                                    'category_name' => 'esportes',
                                    'orderby'       => 'date',
                                    'order'         => 'DESC'
                                ));

                                $count = 0;

                                foreach ($posts as $post):

                                    setup_postdata($post);

                                    if($count == 0): ?>
                                        <article class="news-destaque">
                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                                <figure>
                                                    <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, 'ag-apcef-large'); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                                                </figure>
                                                <div class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
                                            </a>
                                                <div class="content">
                                                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                                </div>

                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="link">Leia mais</a>

                                        </article>
                                    <?php else: ?>
                                        <article class="news-reduced">
                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                                        </article>
                                    <?php endif;

                                    $count++;

                                endforeach; ?>
                            </section>

                            <a href="<?= get_site_url(null, 'category/esportes') ?>" class="btn-list-all" target="_self">Veja todos</a>
                        </div>


                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <section class="news">
                                <h4 class="section-title">
                                    <a href="<?= get_site_url(null, 'category/noticias') ?>" target="_self">Mais Notícias</a>
                                </h4>
                                <?php

                                $posts = get_posts(array(
                                    'numberposts'   => 3,
                                    'post_type'     => 'post',
                                    'category_name' => 'noticias',
                                    'orderby'       => 'date',
                                    'order'         => 'DESC'
                                ));

                                $count = 0;

                                foreach ($posts as $post):

                                    setup_postdata($post);

                                    if($count == 0): ?>
                                        <article class="news-destaque">
                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                                <figure>
                                                    <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, 'ag-apcef-large'); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                                                </figure>
                                                <div class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
                                            </a>
                                            <div class="content">
                                                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                            </div>

                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="link">Leia mais</a>

                                        </article>
                                    <?php else: ?>
                                        <article class="news-reduced">
                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                                        </article>
                                    <?php endif;

                                    $count++;

                                endforeach; ?>
                            </section>

                            <a href="<?= get_site_url(null, 'category/noticias') ?>" class="btn-list-all" target="_self">Veja todos</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                            <section class="news">
                                <h4 class="section-title">
                                    <a href="<?= get_site_url(null, 'category/noticias-fenae') ?>" target="_self">Notícias Fenae</a>
                                </h4>
                                <?php

                                $posts = get_posts(array(
                                    'numberposts'   => 3,
                                    'post_type'     => 'post',
                                    'category_name' => 'noticias-fenae',
                                    'orderby'       => 'date',
                                    'order'         => 'DESC'
                                ));

                                $count = 0;

                                foreach ($posts as $post):

                                    setup_postdata($post);

                                    if($count == 0): ?>
                                        <article class="news-destaque">
                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                                <figure>
                                                    <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, 'ag-apcef-large'); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                                                </figure>
                                                <div class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
                                            </a>
                                            <div class="content">
                                                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                            </div>

                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="link">Leia mais</a>

                                        </article>
                                    <?php else: ?>
                                        <article class="news-reduced">
                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                                        </article>
                                    <?php endif;

                                    $count++;

                                endforeach; ?>
                            </section>

                            <a href="<?= get_site_url(null, 'category/noticias-fenae') ?>" class="btn-list-all" target="_self">Veja todos</a>
                        </div>      





            <!-- Slide unidade de lazer -->

            <div class="col-md-12">
            <p style="border-widget:1px; background-color:#D6D6D6;"> </p>
                        <section id="unidades-de-lazer" class="unidades-de-lazer">
                            <h4 class="section-title">
                                <!-- Remover CSS Inline-->
                                <a href="<?= get_category_link(get_category_by_slug('unidades-de-lazer')->cat_ID); ?>" target="_self" style="color:#F36F21;">
                                    Unidades de Lazer
                                </a>
                            </h4>
                            <section id="unidades-de-lazer-tabs" class="vertical-tabs">
                                <div class="vertical-tabs-wrap">
                                    <ul class="vertical-tabs-nav">
                                        <?php

                                        $count = 0;

                                        $posts = get_posts(array(
                                            'numberposts'   => 8,
                                            'post_type'     => 'unidade-lazer',
                                            'orderby'       => 'date',
                                            'order'         => 'ASC'
                                        ));

                                        foreach ($posts as $post):

                                            setup_postdata($post); ?>

                                            <li <?= ($count == 0) ? 'class="active"' : ''; ?>><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-default-redirect="true"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
                                        <?php

                                        $count++;

                                        endforeach; ?>
                                    </ul>
                                    <ul class="vertical-tabs-items">
                                        <?php

                                        foreach ($posts as $post):

                                            setup_postdata($post); ?>
                                            <li>
                                                <div>
                                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                                        <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, 'ag-apcef-large'); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                                                    </a>
                                                </div>
                                            </li>
                                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </section>
                        </section>
                    </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3" id="sidebar">
            <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Depende do que você quer cara, isso é CSS, vc pode usar o atributo line-height: 15px; ou reduzir a fonte. font-size: 11px;

Comment: tenta isso:  `figcaption p { font-size: 130%;
    line-height: 18px;
    margin-top: 6px; }`

Comment: Só quero diminuir mesmo o espaço entre uma linha e outra. por que está feio assim, e o complicado que preciso manter o tamanho da fonte.

Tentei utilizar esse codigo no css e continua na mesma forma, com espaço grande

Será que tem alguma outra formatação que está fazendo isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode resolver isso aplicando o CSS abaixo ao elemento `<fingcaption><p>`:

```
figcaption p{
  line-height: 1.15em;
  margin-top:10px;
}
```

Você pode fazer um *ajuste fino* no `line-height` alterando com um valor mais preciso depois do ponto, assim: `1.11em`, `1.12em`, `1.13em` e por aí vai.

Ou então você pode colocar o CSS *inline* direto no elemento, assim:

```
<figcaption>
  <p style="line-height: 1.15em; margin-top: 10px;" >
    Texto texto texto....
  </p>
</figcaption>
```

> Se quiser fazer um teste antes de mexer no código, abra o console
>   (F12) na página e execute o código abaixo para ver uma prévia:

```
$("figcaption p").css({"line-height":"1.15em","margin-top":"10px"})
```

Comment: Cara funcionou das 2 maneiras, muito obrigado ! Será que o metodo do ivan não funcionou por que estava em px ?

Comment: @Axcse Isso. Em `px` o valor fica fixo, em `em` o valor é baseado no tamanho da fonte.